# Click disable for some time does't work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have this html element:

```
<div class="s_right hide_text"><a class="crackable" href="#">next</a></div>
```

and I need to disable click action on this element for some time, and i do this:

```
$.fn.disableFor = function (time) {
    var el = this, qname = 'disqueue';
    el.queue(qname, function () {
        el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        setTimeout( function () {
            el.dequeue(qname);
        }, time);
    })
    .queue(qname, function () {
        el.removeAttr('disabled');
    })
    .dequeue(qname);
};

var settings_rc_right = $('.s_right a');

settings_rc_right.on('click', function(){
    $(this).disableFor(2000);
    // actions
});
```

I don't know why but this still works, I can fast click one by one and click call action. Can anybody help me with this? [Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/RDnQ4/2/)

Comment: I don't think you can use `disabled` on a `div`.

Comment: for what element i can do this? button?

Comment: Yep. Buttons and `input` fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` and other form widgets support disabled. For other elements, you could add a disabled css class.

`<a>` needs to be handled differently. You could assign a click handler that does nothing:

```
$("a").click(function(){ return false; });
```

Also, you should be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). See [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: return false; is a little bit old-fashioned as I know, and not recommended to use in this case. Check this documentation: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/  

Probably it's much better to use here: 
    $("a").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: Assuming the OP wants to disable all click handlers and event propagation, `return false` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

Needs to apply `a` like this:

```
$("a").on("click," function(){ return !1; });
// or
$("a").on("mousedown" function(){ return !1; });
```